# HTTP interceptor in angular 7 not adding headers

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to set the auth token in http header by using the below code. It does not set the auth token in header. what am i Missing here? Tried the solution provided in below link but no luck with it.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820257/angular-7-httpinterceptor-not-adding-header-to-request
```

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const token: string = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
        request = request.clone({ url: `${this.baseUrl}/${request.url}` });

        const clonedRequest = request.clone({
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                Authorization: token,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            })
        });
        return next.handle(clonedRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `token` is not null? You can try the [sample from here](https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/app/core/interceptors/http.token.interceptor.ts)

Comment: token is not null... in fact I am unable to see content-type also in headers

Comment: Did you try `setHeaders` instead of `headers`? Also the request is cloned twice. Is it necessary?

Comment: i tried with ```setHeaders``` it sets the values in request.headers.headers.lazyupdate

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it due to the missing "" around Authorization?

Comment: Try adding Bearer to token, e.g Authorization: 'Bearer ${token}'